# Angular 6 get List of Objects in List Using a Key/Property

Tags: angular, typescript

The **getEntities()** method in **Entity1Service.ts** returns the following error.

`Type 'Entity1' is not assignable to type 'Entity1[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Entity1'`

What is the correct way to get a list of objects that contain an id number associated to another entity? This application is using Angular 6.

**Entity1.ts**

```
export class Entity1 {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    entitiy2Id: number;

    constructor(
        _id: number,
        _name: string,
        _entity2Id: number
    ) {
        this.id = _id,
        this.name = _name
        this.entity2Id = _entity2Id
    }
}
```

**Entity2.ts**

```
export class Entity2 {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(
        _id: number,
        _name: string
    ) {
        this.id = _id;
        this.name = _name;
    }
}
```

**Entity1Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Entity1 } from './models/entity1';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Entity1Service {

  entities: Enity1[] = [
    { 
      id: 1,
      name: 'First',
      entity2Id: 1 
    },
    { 
      id: 2,
      name: 'Second',
      entity2Id: 1 
    },
    { 
      id: 3,
      name: 'Third',
      entity2Id: 1 
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  getEntities(_entity2Id: number): Entity1[] {
    // The following line does not work
    return this.entities.find(entity => entity.entity2Id === _entity2Id);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`find()`** will return only 1 matching element, use **`filter()`** instead since your method needs to return an **`[]`**

```
return this.entities.filter(entity => entity.entity2Id === _entity2Id);
```